# Manipulate a Rubik's Cube in Prolog

Tags: prolog, rubiks-cube

I want to do some basic rotations on a scrambled Rubik cube in prolog untill it's solved.
I am thinking of saving  the cube as lists like so:

```
[w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w],
[b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b],
[g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g],
[r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r],
[o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o],
[y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y] ...but scrambled
```

How can I implement rotations(R,U,F,B,D,L) , so that when I do a U rotation, my cube will look something like this:

```
 [w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w],
 [r,r,r,b,b,b,b,b,b],
 [o,o,o,g,g,g,g,g,g],
 [g,g,g,r,r,r,r,r,r],
 [b,b,b,o,o,o,o,o,o],
 [y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y]    ???
```

So I want to write some rotations in console and the program to return true if cube is solved or false if isn't.

If someone has some ideas I would be greatful to see them :)

Comment: SWI-Prolog has a contribution (from 1993) you can browse

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27462781/1613573), where a related simpler task is discussed.